# png image files work find but jpg files fail on my web server

Tags: php, apache2, png, jpeg

I recently upgraded from linux mint 14 to linux mint 16 (both 64 bit) and using php5 apache2 and have tryed to load up my web server and the jpg files (images) all fail to load even tho there readable and exist but the png files all work any idea what I need to do to fix this?

(its localhost not hosted).
read permissions are also set for the folders that hold the images.

Answer (score 0):

Double check and make sure that you have the jpg files set to 644 perms as its most likely the issue there.

Can you also let us know if you are getting any error, maybe a screencast of what you are getting.

Comment: the perms are same thoughout for png and jpg files and only the jpg files are not displayed and pngs are fine all permissions are fine and there are no error messages

Comment: on exif it sais Supported filetypes JPEG,TIFF  on phpinfo but its not mentioning jpg file type would that be an issue?

Comment: with the extension being set to .jpg it should not make any difference unless your apache install is not configured correctly.  You can try changing to .jpeg and see if that makes a difference, if it does then make sure to configure apache correctly to assign .jpg as .jpeg

Comment: what shall i check in my apache conf file to add an extension handler as i have had issues and have reinstalled php5 and apache2 files just last night so if needed i can post any file or part of a conf file needed i have also been looking on google but exif mainly referes to httpd but not apache2 what i want to know is what is the best apache linux web server to attempt to install instaead of apache2 for linux if required i can try a new server if its better then apache2 php5 5.5.3-1

Answer (score 0):

```
 sudo chmod 775 images folder

 sudo chmod 775 user/usernames/folder

 sudo chmod 775 header files
```

seems to of made it work it seems it was the permissions thanks for your help everyone